# Split a column into multiple columns of its factors by unique ID

Tags: r, split

I have a dataframe of transactional data, for example:

```
ID   TYPE    QUANTITY
01    A    2
01    B    1
01    C    4
02    A    3
02    C    2
03    C    3
```

I need to split `ID` by the factors in `TYPE` and from those factors create new columns that contain the `QUANTITY` value for each column.

So that it will look like this:

```
ID    A    B    C
01    2    1    4
02    3    0    2
03    0    0    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast()` from `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID ~ TYPE, fun.aggregate = sum)
  ID A B C
1  1 2 1 4
2  2 3 0 2
3  3 0 0 3
```

Comment: hehe, lets see who wins this time, reshape2 or tidyr ;-)

Comment: @Linus It's on :-D

Comment: Both are valid answers! I am assuming the greater benefit of the answer from @PoGibas is this will include the sum of `QUANTITY` in rare cases that `ID` and `TYPE` are both the same?

Comment: @STACKin yes and it doesn’t introduce ‘NA’

Answer (score 2):

use the tidyr package and make your long format to a wide format

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, key = 'TYPE', value= 'QUANTITY')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically using `base r`

```
reshape(data,v.names="QUANTITY",timevar = "TYPE",idvar = "ID",direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Although the use of `cast` or `dcast` or `recast` or even `acast` from `reshape` and `reshape2` packages depending on what is needed might be quite easy to follow and manipulate.